# jquery get specific input value from clicked button on form when multiple forms on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on the same page but need to get the values of the input element when a particular form is clicked i.e

However the jquery returns undefined query i

**MY SCRIPT to get the values**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.theform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $(this).find(".product").val();
    alert(user);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$product='productOne';
<form class="theform">
  <input id="" class='product' name="product" value="<?php echo $product; ??>" style="display: none">

  <input type="hidden" class="userName" name="userName" value="john759">
  <button class="action">Click</button>
</form>

$product='productTwo';
<form class="theform">
  <input id="" class='product' name="product" value="<?php echo $product; ?>" style="display: none">
  <input type="hidden" class="userName" name="userName" value="dDuck">
  <button class="action">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It should be `.theform` not `.myform`. Fix that and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5bcmgLuq/

Comment: Hi rory. i am sorry but it does not work. your example also does not work

Comment: @user3389187 it's working man i've checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this:

```
var user = $(this).find(".product").val();
```

use:

```
var user = $(this).parent().find(".product").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ***closest*** function to get ***closset*** form value;

```
$(this).closest('form').find(".product").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type of button

```
<button class="action" type="submit">Click</button>
```

Comment: You want value of hidden fields?